# ${\partial\over{\partial x_j}}\left(\partial x_i\over\partial t\right)\ne{\partial\over{\partial t}}\left(\partial x_i\over\partial x_j\right)$?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, derivatives, calculus

$ \boldsymbol x = f(\boldsymbol X,t)$ is the position of a particle in an instant of time

$\boldsymbol X$ is the initial position

$t$ time

$\boldsymbol u$ velocity

In my opnion $f$ is continuos...

Considering:

$$u_i={{\partial x_i}\over{\partial t}}$$

Then:

$${\partial \over {\partial x_j}} \left(\partial x_i \over \partial t \right) = {{\partial u_i}\over{\partial x_j}}=\boldsymbol{\nabla}\boldsymbol{u}$$

But we **can't** Invert the Order of the partial derivative, otherwise we would have:

$${\partial \over {\partial t}} \left(\partial x_i \over \partial x_j \right) \neq 0$$

That is not the same result.

Comment: the bar represents what? averaged values?

Comment: this is a question for the mathematics.SE

Comment: vector notation , but I will change to indices right now to be easier to understand

Comment: anna v, according to mathematics, if x=f(X,t) is continuous and defined, it is possible, but the position function isn't continuous??

Comment: This question makes no sense if the function isn't second-order continuous in both time and space. Some engineers deal with non-nice functions (e.g., noise) because they have to do so. Some mathematicians deal with non-nice functions because they want to do so. Physicists on the other hand primarily deal with nice functions because they don't want to be insane engineers or mathematicians.

Answer (score 3):

In the equation $\vec{u}=\frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial t}$, it is $\vec{X}$ that is being held constant (i.e., the material particle is being held constant):$$\vec{u}=\left(\frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial t}\right)_{\vec{X}}$$In the expression for the velocity gradient tensor $\nabla \vec{u}$, it is time that is being held constant, while the gradient is taken with respect to the **current positions** of all particles.  So the operations are not commutative.

Answer (score 2):

You should really consider using vector and/or index notation more consistently; have in index notation:
$$u_i={{\partial x_i}\over{\partial t}}$$
which gives:
$${\partial \over {\partial x_j}} \left(\partial x_i \over \partial t \right) = {{\partial u_i}\over{\partial x_j}}=\boldsymbol{\nabla}\boldsymbol{u}$$
The bold symbols are in vector notation. Then:
$${\partial \over {\partial t}} \left(\partial x_i \over \partial x_j \right) \neq 0$$

necessarily right?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but is the last "not equal" equation ok with mathematics??

Comment: Thanks! Is it right to cahnge this order of derivatives??